# Adding a string (subdomain) to the front of URL with Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I've been searching but couldn't find much info on this.

Basically, I'm building a (PHP based) website, and for my own language switching implementation I need to have buttons that I can click and it would redirect to the exact same page in the selected language. For example: http://example.com/page1?param1 to http://es.example.com/page1?param1.

Is there any way to do this with javascript or php?

Thanks!

Comment: you need ah subdomain? create the subdomain on your hosting panel.Then you easly redirect with your main domain to subdomain .like `href` event

Comment: Unfortunately creating subdomains isn't the problem here, I've already created them. Essentially what I want is to have the button redirecting to exactly the same page as the current page but in a different language, and this can't be done with HTML code alone (?)

Answer (score 1):

With PHP, it's easy to find the current URL:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` -> `/page1?param1`
`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` -> `example.com`

You can easily use this information to add links, buttons or menu to other language versions

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I ended up going with your one as it's the most simple in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL in JavaScript using:

```
window.location.href
```

So your button could call a function and pass in a value to that function. And then using a regular expression you can insert your language variable in the appropriate spot.

```
<button id='esLanguage' onclick="changeLanguage('es')"></button>

function changeLanguage(language) {

    var url = window.location.href
    var newUrl = url.replace(/^http:\/\//, 'http://' + language + '.')

    windows.location = newUrl;
}
```

This is all assuming you have sub domains set up for each language.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can do this:

```js
window.location.host = `subdomain.${window.location.host}`
```

Be aware, this is going to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for the current `window.location`:

```
function withSubdomain(path = window.location.pathname, subdomain = 'blog') {
    const { protocol, host } = window.location;

    return `${protocol}//${subdomain}.${host}${path}`;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.you should include your subdomain path in href then click the link it will auto redirect to the page.

```html
<a href="http://es.example.com/page1?param1">param1</a>
<a href="http://es.example.com/page1?param2">param2</a>
<a href="http://es.example.com/page1?param3">param3</a>
<a href="http://es.example.com/page1?param4">param4</a>
<a href="http://es.example.com/page1?param5">param5</a>
.
.
.
..
```

Note:*
each link is the new html pages